# query execstack at runtime

Tags: linux, stack, executable, detection

I am hacking a plugin that requires the host-application to allow an *executable stack*.

This can be achieved by running

```
execstack -s /path/to/my/host
```

However, if the host application lacks the *executable stack* flag (e.g. the above command has not been called), running my plugin simply crashes the host:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

I would like to avoid the crash, e.g. by disabling parts of my code automatically if the *executable stack* lag is *not* set.

The check should happen at runtime during the plugin initialization

However, I haven't found any documentation on how to detect the availability of the *executable stack* at runtime (without crashing).

The only thing I have found so far is `execstack -q /path/to/my/host`, but that seems hacky to run from within a plugin loaded by /path/to/my/host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it seems there is better solution to my problem than *querying* the protection scheme in runtime: explicitely flag a memory to be executable, using

```
int mprotect(void *addr, size_t len, int prot);
```

this basically adds an exception to the `executable stack protection` in a well defined memory region.